# Weak solution in a PDE. Example in Barry Simon.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

Hello. I am trying to prove that the function $u(x, t)$ of the example is a weak solution in a direct way (with the definition), but, I cannot understand why $u\in\mathcal{D}'$
(This because definition V.5 requires $u$ to be a distribution)
Why $u\in\mathcal{D}'$?

Comment: Note that $u\in L^1\subset \mathcal{D}'$, acting on functions in $\mathcal{D}$ by $f\mapsto \int f u$

Comment: Then $u:\mathcal{D}\to \mathbb{C}$ with $u(f)(x)=\int f(x)u(x,t)dx$ but, what happen with $t$?
For each $t$, $u(\cdot ,t)\mathcal{D}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that for all $g\in \mathcal{D}$, $u(g)(x)=\int g(x)u(x,t)dx?$

Comment: I meant $u\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)\subset \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: I understand. But, Why u is a weak solution? I have this: Let $\varphi\in\mathcal{D}$ then $(\partial_{t}^2-c^2\partial_{x}^2)(u)(\varphi)=u((\partial_{t}^2-c^2\partial_{x}^2)\varphi(x,t))$
$=\int \int u(x,t)(\partial_{t}^2-c^2\partial_{x}^2)\varphi(x,t)dxdt$
$=\int \int_{ct<=x<=1+ct} (\partial_{t}^2-c^2\partial_{x}^2)\varphi(x,t)dxdt$ This is correct? And, i want proves that it is zero.

Comment: Yep. Now solve that integral, first the one in dx then in dt (or viceversa)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the problem is to compute for $\varphi\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,t)(\varphi_{tt}-c^2\varphi_{xx})\mathrm dx\mathrm dt=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{ct-1}^{ct+1} (\varphi_{tt}-c^2\varphi_{xx})\mathrm dx\mathrm dt\\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{\frac{x-1}{c}}^{\frac{x+1}{c}} \varphi_{tt}\mathrm dt \mathrm dx-c^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{ct-1}^{ct+1}\varphi_{xx}\mathrm dx\mathrm dt
$$
splitting the integral and using Fubini's theorem. For the first integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{\frac{x-1}{c}}^{\frac{x+1}{c}} \varphi_{tt}\mathrm dt \mathrm dx=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi_{t}\left(\frac{x+1}{c} \right) \mathrm dx-
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi_{t}\left(\frac{x-1}{c} \right) \mathrm dx
$$
and changing variables
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi_{t}\left(\frac{x-1}{c} \right) \mathrm dx=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi_{t}\left(\frac{x+1}{c} \right) \mathrm dx=c
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi_{t}\left(u \right) \mathrm du
$$
and the first integral vanishes. The second integral vanishes by similar logic.

Comment: Thank you very much, this clarified many doubts I had.

Comment: @eraldcoil not a problem. I'm glad it was helpful.